# In SVG is there a way to tell child elements to NOT transform with the parent?

Tags: css, svg

Here is a simple situation.  I have a triangle with text next to it.

```
<svg style="background-color:silver" width="100%" height="100%">
    <path d="M 0,0 L 100,100 L0,100 Z" />
    <text x="50" y="50" font-size="5mm">Text</text>
</svg>
```

I can easily tell the triangle to resize as the canvas resizes by adding a viewBox.

```
<svg style="background-color:silver" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 0,0 L 100,100 L0,100 Z" />
    <text x="50" y="50" font-size="5mm">Text</text>
</svg>
```

The problem with this is that it scales the text as well, which I do not want.
I can't move the text outside of this viewBox,because I need the x, y position to scale.

I have a work-around by creating two canvases, one for the graphic, and one for the text, and then placing one on top of the other.  This requires the top canvas to have a transparent background, which from what I am reading is NOT supported by the SVG standard.

I have a work-around by using a second SVG canvas on top of thcan't move the text to another SVG because 
I can't This might be fine, if I had an image and was trying to zoom in.  But I'm thinking more of a map, where when you zoom in, the text stays the same size.

So my question is how do I keep the text size constant?

I have seen other people use JavaScript to dynamically read the transform used by the viewBox and creating an inverse transform for the text.  I really don't want to introduce a dynamic script, when all I want to do is have static, non-dynamic text.

Comment: Edited capitalized SVG tags to lowercase.

Comment: Added the `css` tag because the accepted answer relies on usage of `css`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to BigBadaboom for pointing out that SVG can have transparent backgrounds.
This means that my work-around is actually an acceptable solution.

```
<div>
<svg style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:silver" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <path d="M 0,0 L 100,100 L0,100 Z" />
</svg>
<svg style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:transparent">
    <text x="50%" y="50%" font-size="5pt">Text</text>
</svg>
</div>
```

The `position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px` places both canvases in the same location.
The `viewBox"0 0 100 100"` in the first svg tag makes the unit-less numbers in the path behave like percentages.
The lack of a `viewBox` in the second svg tag allows the text tag to use percentages for the positioning (like the first svg tag) while using an absolute unit for the font-size.

The result is that the entire picture resizes, while keeping the text at the specified font-size.

Answer (score 1):

> This requires the top canvas to have a transparent background, which
>   from what I am reading is NOT supported by the SVG standard.

This is incorrect.  There is nothing in the SVG spec that says that SVGs have an opaque background.

> So my question is how do I keep the text size constant?

There is really no way to do this other than the script approach you mentioned.